# ASP.NET MVC Routing for files with muliple sub-directories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I need to setup a file handler to route with multiple sub directories something like tihs;

```
http://localhost/images/7/99/786936215595.jpg
```

I tried putting this in the global.asax file;

```
 routes.Add(
   "ImageRoute",
   new Route("covers/{filepath}/{filename}",
   new ImageRouteHandler()));
```

I am using the ImageHandler found in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146652/how-do-i-route-images-using-asp-net-mvc-routing), which works great if you have a single sub-directory (ie '/images/15/786936215595.jpg') but fails when you have multiple directories.

I tried setting up a wildcard and that didnt work (ie 'new Route("covers/{filepath}/*/{filename}"')

This is serving images from a large NAS (think something like 3 million images) so its not like I can just move files around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after much playing around and google fu I found how to make it work.

Change the route definition like this;

```
 routes.Add(
     "ImageRoute",
     new Route("images/{*filepath}",
     new ImageRouteHandler()));
```

Then put this after the default MapRoute. The important part is the "*" before the filepath, tells MVC to send anything following this as part of the filepath RouteData. So in the GetHttpHandler() method I can get the full path by using this;

```
string fp = requestContext.RouteData.Values["filepath"] as string;
```

Woot!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you treat the entire path as one route parameter? Like so:

```
routes.Add(
    "ImageRoute",
    "/images/{path}",
    new { controller = "Image", action = "Image" }
);
```

And then access the entire path in the `ActionResult Image(string path) { }` action method?