# How do I create a changing image for my website?

Tags: image

Not long ago I came across this website: http://www.danasoft.com/
This websites provides dynamically updating signatures which are pretty cool in my opinion.
There is just one thing that I don't get and would really like to know how to do.
Here's a direct link to an image on the website: http://www.danasoft.com/vipersig.jpg Try refreshing. Notice it changes? How do I achieve that? How do I have a direct link to a file like www.mypage.com/thing.jpeg output different images each time?

Comment: use a cgi and generate an image on the fly using libgd, imagemagick, and friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the URL is not actually retrieving the file directly each time, but rather the server is intercepting that URL and serving a (possibly random) image from a larger set of images. Depending on whether the server is running Apache, IIS, etc, the implementation could vary... This could also probably be achieved with the [MVC routing engine](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) by defining a custom route handler for URLs ending in '.jpg', but I'm not actually sure.

**EDIT:**

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146652/how-do-i-route-images-using-asp-net-mvc-routing) for more detail on the MVC implementation.