# MVC 3 routing problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my site i have the following routing table:

```
routes.MapRoute("Something",
                "sites/{company}/{site}/",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "LoadClientSite" },
                new[] { "CorrectOnLine.Controllers" });

routes.MapRoute("Default1", // Route name
                "{company}/{site}/", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "DefaultRedirect" },
                new[] { "CorrectOnLine.Controllers" }
            );

routes.MapRoute("Default2", // Route name
                "{company}/{site}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "DefaultRedirect" },
                new[] { "CorrectOnLine.Controllers" }
            );
```

I am using the following link to call an action:

```
@(Html.Action("index", "home", new { area = "ClientsSites", CompanyID = Model.CompanyID, SiteID = Model.SiteID, CategoryID = Model.CategoryID, Message = Model.Message }))
```

In the view i have an image:

```
<img alt="" src="../../../../../WareHouse/Sites/logo_site_@(Model.Site.SiteID).jpg" height="250px" width="750px" />
```

The problem is that when the image loades MVC tries to locate the image src in the routing table , conntroller = WareHouse, action = Sites.

How can i make MVC to only load the iamge and not try to load it as a view?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I believe this post will help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146652/how-do-i-route-images-using-asp-net-mvc-routing

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore route for all paths that end in the .jpg extension...

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*alljpeg}", new {alljpeg=@".*\.jpg(/.*)?"});
```