# Robust ways to handle multiple image locations within the file system in C# MVC .NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filesystems

Within my application I have multiple file locations that hold different types of images.   I'm wondering how I should handle these locations within my MVC application?

I want to achieve the following:

- Make the image locations easily reusable within my MVC application (within views to display and within controllers for image uploads)
- Make the linking/uploading to the image locations less error-prone
- Store the locations some how within the application

For example I have the following places within the file system:

- ~/Content/Images/ImageType1
- ~/Content/Images/ImageType2
- ~/Content/Images/ImageType3
- ~/Content/Images/ImageType4

These are the following options that I've found so far:

1. Just link to the images within the tags (error-prone)

   `eg. <img src="~/Content/Images/ImageType4/{imagefilename}">`
2. Helper method to display each type of image
3. [Creating a route for each image location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146652/how-do-i-route-images-using-asp-net-mvc-routing)

Are there any other ways that I haven't thought of?

Comment: I am not sure what is supported out of the box for .NET MVC but as I have seen from other frameworks:  https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle  . They store in a file or in initialize code a list of types in order to be reusable along with size ,path etc specifications. Of course you might need a helper for your view and a dependency injection or whatever for your controller.Also I suggest direct access to images to avoid routing overhead etc.

Comment: I hadn't actually considered the routing overhead of using the routing system, maybe just a HTML helper for each image location would suffice for my needs.

Comment: Here are some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files