# ASP.NET MVC Security - Images and Files Dynamic Path in Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I am covering some security vulnerabilities in my ASP.NT MVC Web App, and I don't want every one to know my structure, folders name, orany information that could help him to attack me. So I want to know is it possible to encyrpt the file/images paths and how to?
Or if any one have any suggestion.

Normal Output:

```
  ~/Images/Articles/hgasdh7y8273y82.png   //Real Path
```

Desired Output:

```
  /anything/anything/hgasdh7y8273y82.png    //Fake Path
```

**P.S: I already tried to make it with generic handler, but it affects the performance badly.**

Thanks

Comment: Is it really that much of an issue that they know your image folder? It's not like you have directory browsing enabled or anything (well you shouldn't :)).

Comment: @mattytommo Its important to secure your Image path, and don't provide it easily to hackers

Comment: Why? What exactly are they going to do with the image path? It's not like they can find that, then navigate elsewhere as I say you wouldn't have directory browsing turned on anyway.

Comment: To answer your question though, your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146652/how-do-i-route-images-using-asp-net-mvc-routing